# What does pid 0 mean for sched_setaffinity()

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I'm seeing such code in [nginx source](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L893):

```
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, 32, (cpu_set_t *) &cpu_affinity) == -1) {
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT, cycle->log, ngx_errno,
                      "sched_setaffinity(0x%08Xl) failed", cpu_affinity);
    }
```

Why here `pid` is `0` instead of `getpid()`?

Answer (score 3):

From the [`sched_setaffinity(2)` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html):

> The affinity mask is actually a per-thread attribute that can be
>   adjusted independently for each of the threads in a thread group. The
>   value returned from a call to [`gettid(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettid.2.html) can be passed in the argument
>   pid. **Specifying `pid` as 0 will set the attribute for the calling
>   thread, and passing the value returned from a call to [`getpid(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpid.2.html) will
>   set the attribute for the main thread of the thread group.** (If you are
>   using the POSIX threads API, then use [`pthread_setaffinity_np(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) instead
>   of `sched_setaffinity()`.)

Comment: will it affect the child process that are `fork()`ed?

Comment: @compile-fan Yes it will. A child created via `fork(2)` inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask.  The affinity mask is preserved across an `execve(2)`.